# Storing the output of a compiled template in a variable rather than rendering it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

By running a method I would like to fetch the output of a compiled erb-template and store it in a variable instead of rendering it.

I would like to be able to use rails' helper functions (e.g. distance_of_time_in_words_to_now or including partials) in the template.

How would I go about that?

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section. This is a very broad question. Perhaps you should do some research, give some things a try, and then come back when you have more specific questions that we can help with.

Comment: Look at Ruby's [ERB](https://apidock.com/ruby/ERB) class.

Comment: You're looking for [`render partial:`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)